# ProxyOverrideError Apache tomact 9.0

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy

i want be able to find what is causing Apache to replace all non 2XX responses with its own error document. All i need to do is, comment or set off ProxyErrorOverride. With this Apache will proxy pass error response as is from backend server to UI without loosing content, example it sends error response of type Json as it is without loosing headers.but i don't know how to set this variable and where. any help pls?

Comment: The configuration file of Apache HTTP Server is usually split into many files. What OS are you using and how did you install Apache2?

Comment: i'm using windows 10 and Apache Tomcat 9
Version 9.0.48 installed from the internet

Comment: Any suggests..its urgent!

Comment: The main configuration file is always `conf/httpd.conf`, but it might include other files (the exact files included depend on the exact distribution you downloaded from the _"Internet"_). `ProxyErrorOverride` defaults to `Off`, so you must have changed it to `On` explicitly.

Comment: I'm facing two problemes here : 1- the apache i've downloded it does not have the file httpd.conf and 2-i'm tring to set it off so the apche does not change the content type of the server response wich is json and as u say it is by default off so no need..the problem now is why the respnse i'm getting from the server is text/html content and not json and i've already have application json response content type in my webservices at the backend

Comment: any suggests pls?

Comment: Can you explain better your configuration? How are you proxying requests using Tomcat? Usually Apache is an abbreviation for [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) and the HTTP Server is a reverse proxy (via modules), Tomcat isn't.

Comment: I've downloded it from here "https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi",my configuration is i'm having a web application with an angular front calling rest service delete of an entity at the spring backend , the problem is the response i'm getting from the back is html/txt content type or my webservices consume and produce application json responses

Comment: Tomcat does not change the error messages returned by an application. My guess is: your Angular application calls the wrong URL and you get a `404` response. Check with a simple HTTP client (e.g. `curl`) what error are you getting.

Comment: it's a État HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error exception returned , front application is calling for the rest service delete of the back